# CartoCSS layer visibility

Tags: tilemill, mapbox, cartocss

I am working in TileMill and I have a number of layers in two different levels of detail. I have assigned classes to the layers "highdetail" and "lowdetail", and I know how to use the zoom selector - now how can I hide all the low detail layers when zoomed in past e.g. zoom level 6?
The layers are a mix of polygon/raster/line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `opacity` instead of `display:none;`

```
#idToHide[zoom=6] {

  polygon-opacity: 0;
  raster-opacity: 0;
  line-opacity: 0;
  text-opacity: 0;

}
```

source: https://www.mapbox.com/carto/api/2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

You would use zoom filters for this: see [Advanced map design](https://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/advanced-map-design/), and notice the bits that say things like `[zoom=6]` or `[zoom>10]`.

Comment: yeah, but I would have to do that for each layer, right? What I am missing is something equivalent to display:none from CSS!